# TSQL - compare dates (year and calendar week) formatted as strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need a way to compare dates in the following string format: **`'2015 CW 14'`** or **`'2016 CW 03'`**'
with the **current year and week** in order to test if the value is in the **past** or **>=** the *current year and week*.

```
DECLARE @cw VARCHAR(50) 

SET @cw = '2015 CW 13' 

SELECT @cw; 

SELECT Cast(Year(Getdate()) AS VARCHAR(50)) 
       + ' CW ' 
       + Cast(Datepart(week, Getdate()) AS VARCHAR(50))
```

I believe my approach won't get me there.

Comment: Not completely sure what you are trying to do. Could you elaborate some more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have a problem on `2016 CW 03` I edit your statement to `@cw2`, And you can see `<` or `>` or `=` will work for comparing.

This clue can be useful:

```
DECLARE @cw  VARCHAR(50), 
        @cw2 VARCHAR(50) 

SET @cw = '2015 CW 03' 
SET @cw2 = Cast(Year(Getdate()) AS VARCHAR(50)) 
           + ' CW ' 
           + RIGHT('00' + Cast(Datepart(week, Getdate()) AS VARCHAR(50)), 2) 

SELECT @cw, 
       @cw2, 
       CASE 
         WHEN @cw = @cw2 THEN 0 
         WHEN @cw < @cw2 THEN -1 
         ELSE 1 
       END
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the only safe and easy way is to compare the `int` values separately, as you cannot compare the strings correctly with `>=` without manipulation, and converting to dates is complex and redundant. The `int` comparison will look like this (edited):

```
declare @cw varchar(10)
set @cw = '2015 CW 17'
Select
    Case 
        When CAST(LEFT(@cw, 4) as int) > DATEPART(yy, GETDATE())  
        Or ( CAST(LEFT(@cw, 4) as int) = DATEPART(yy, GETDATE()) 
            And CAST(RIGHT(@cw, 2) as int) >= DATEPART(ww, GETDATE()) )
        Then 'future' 
        Else 'past' 
    End as IntCompare
```

Comment: This leaves you open to the situation where your year might be greater but your week number less. So, if `@cw = '2016 CW 14'` and the current week is 15, your code will treat `@cw` as a past date.

Comment: Right! I thought I checked it. Rookie mistake. I will edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
DECLARE @cw VARCHAR(50) = '2015 CW 16'; 
DECLARE @d DATE = DATEADD(week, CAST(RIGHT(@cw, 2) AS INT) - 1, LEFT(@cw, 4) + '-01-01');

SELECT [Date] = @d
     , [When] =
           CASE
               WHEN DATEPART(week, @d) - DATEPART(week, GETDATE()) = 0 AND YEAR(@d) = YEAR(GETDATE()) THEN 'Current'
               WHEN DATEPART(week, @d) - DATEPART(week, GETDATE()) > 0 THEN 'Future'           
               ELSE 'Past'
           END;
```