# user defined function (TSQL) non deterministic and computed persisted column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, udf, persisted-column

I have a table, which among it's columns there are two columns of type `INT` and they are called:

```
ExpirationMonth
```

and

```
ExpirationYear
```

I want to add a new column to this table, whose value will be calculated based on the values of `ExpirationMonth` and  `ExpirationYear`. So this column would be a computed column.

For this purpose, I have created a user defined scalar function that calculates the value of this column based on the values of `ExpirationMonth` and  `ExpirationYear`. The defintion of the function is the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[IsExpired]
(
    @ExpirationMonth INT,
    @ExpirationYear INT
)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Today DATE = GETDATE()
    DECLARE @PreviousMonth INT = MONTH(@today)-1
    DECLARE @CurrentYear INT = YEAR(@today)

    DECLARE @IsExpired BIT = 0

    IF(@ExpirationYear<@CurrentYear OR
      (@ExpirationYear=@CurrentYear AND @ExpirationMonth<=@PreviousMonth))
        SET @IsExpired = 1

    RETURN @IsExpired

END
```

Initially, I tried to add the column as below:

```
ALTER Table_Name
ADD IsExpired AS [dbo].[IsExpired]([ExpirationMonth], [ExpirationYear]) PERSISTED
```

And I got the following error:

> Computed column 'IsExpired' in table 'Table_Name' cannot be persisted
>   because the column is non-deterministic.

I removed the `PERSISTED` from the above statement and I ran it again. Then I noticed that the column had been added with the expected values.

My question is how can I make this column to be persisted, if that is possible at all?

I realized that the reason for this error is the usage of the `GETDATE` function in the `IsExpired` function. Since `GETDATE` is not deterministic, the `IsExpired` is not deterministic.

However, I don't see how we could make this function, `IsExpired`, to be deterministic and as a result to define the computed column as persisted, if that is possible at all.

Could you please tell me if that's possible and if it is, how can I do this.

Comment: You can save on the overhead of calling the function by just using the expression in the computed column statement.

Comment: Would it suit your needs to create a view of the table, rather than creating a function? This way, every time you query the view it can re-calculate whether or not the product has passed it's expiry date. I think some of the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29728026/tsql-compare-dates-year-and-calendar-week-formatted-as-strings/29728857?noredirect=1#comment47639066_29728857) could actually help you here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am sorry but I didn't get you. You suggest I pass the `GETDATE`  to the `IsExpired` as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is nondeterministic because it's dependent on the current date.  You can't persist computed columns whose values can change over time.

See [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx) on MSDN for more information on Deterministic Functions.

Comment: Hi, I am aware of this. Could you see any way in which we could refactor the user defined function, in order to be deterministic and provide the expected result?

Comment: Sorry, but it's not possible.  You're asking for a column's value to change over time, which is by definition nondeterministic.

Comment: thanks for the article. I read it. It's quite informative. I will leave active the question for some time, in case of taking any other valuable input as yours. if we don't take any other input, I will mark your answer as the solution. (+1) for me. Thank you dude !

Comment: No problem!  You might also consider not using a computed column, and instead adding this calculation to a view.  Not much difference, just keeps your table a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing it in a view

```
SELECT * INTO yourTable
FROM (VALUES(2015,1),(2015,2),(2015,3),(2015,4),(2015,5),(2015,6)) AS A(ExpirationYear,ExpirationMonth);
GO

CREATE VIEW vw_Expiration
AS
SELECT  ExpirationYear,
        ExpirationMonth,
        CASE
            WHEN    ExpirationYear < YEAR(GETDATE()) OR
                    (ExpirationYear = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND ExpirationMonth <= MONTH(GETDATE()))
                THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS IsExpired
FROM yourTable;
GO

SELECT *
FROM vw_Expiration
```

Results:

```
ExpirationYear ExpirationMonth IsExpired
-------------- --------------- -----------
2015           1               1
2015           2               1
2015           3               1
2015           4               1
2015           5               0
2015           6               0
```